# Java: need to see if each char in input string, matches any char in "alphabet"

Tags: java, string, compare

I am implementing a DFA.  The given alphabet is {a, b}.

I've got it telling me if the input string is accepted or not.  (it's got an easy "accept" rule -- the first & last character of the input string must be the same)

What I am trying to do, though, is to check if each character in the input string, is allowed per the prescribed "alphabet".

So, as a boolean, it would return false if the input string is "abcdefg" (for instance)... and it would return true if the input string is "abbaabbbbba" (for instance)

I need to check if a is in the alphabet... then if b is in the alphabet... then if c is in the alphabet... and so forth for each character in the input string.

I've tried variations of loops of different kinds, (I don't remember every single variation!) comparing inputString.charAt(i) with each character in the alphabet... but so far nothing is working like i need/want it to.

for instance, right now I'm trying:

```
  public boolean isInAlphabet(String inputString) {
    if(inputString == " ") {
      System.out.println("   -> empty string is not in our alphabet");
      return false;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
      Character check = inputString.charAt(i);
      System.out.print(check);  // just to see what it's doing

      if(check.equals(alphabet.charAt(0)) || check.equals(alphabet.charAt(1))) {
        System.out.println("   -> your input string is in our alphabet");

        return true;
      }
      else{
        System.out.println("   -> your input string is *not* in our alphapet");
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

the alphabet is represented as:

```
String alphabet = "ab";
```

and the input string is like:

```
String inputString = "abcdefg";
```

Thing is, it stops checking after it finds that the first character in the input string, is in the alphabet.

Like:

```
test input string: abcdefg
is test input string in our alphabet?
a   -> your input string is in our alphabet
```

... and that's all the further checking it does.

How do I get it to check the whole input string -- each character of the input string, against the alphabet?

Like i said, I can't even remember all the things I've tried so far, but it's been at least a dozen.  The more I try the more confused I get.  This feels so easy, but yet I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Comment: Move `System.out.println("   -> your input string is in our alphabet");return true;` out of the `for` loop and replace the last `return false` with it. Because you only want to `return true;` after you've checked every letter and each has passed.

Comment: Well, crap... I *knew* it was easy.  Thank you -- that is working!  And I feel like an idiot now.  I should have asked like two hours ago... haha!

Comment: `if(inputString == " ")` is not how you compare Strings in java

Comment: Also, consider using: [`alphabet.indexOf(check)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)). This will allow you to use any length alphabet.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp : how do I incorporate that correctly, in this?
When I do:
`if(alphabet.indexOf(check))`

(just replacing the 'if' condition in other words, leaving the rest as-is)
i get:
`error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean`
...I'd been trying to figure out how to use indexOf() before too and had gotten stuck.

Comment: It will return `-1` if the letter is not in the string. So `if (alphabet.indexOf(check) == -1) { // Not in string....}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming here that if alphabet contains all the characters from inputString and inputString's first and last character same then it's valid.

But for example, Alphabet = {a,b} and the inputString="aaaaa". So, I am assuming this input also will be valid. (If that's what you are looking for then you can use the following logic to solve it.)
I am taking HashSet for alphabet and then we can iterate the whole string and check whether alphabet contains it or not. The below code is used to convert a string of alphabet to HashSet.

```
    String str="ab";
    for(char ch:str.toCharArray()){
        alphabet.add(ch);
    }
```

Now, to implement a method to check for valid input, you can consider the below code.

```
public boolean isInAlphabet(String inputString) {
    if(inputString==null || inputString.length()==0) return false;
    if(inputString.charAt(0)!=inputString.charAt(inputString.length()-1)) return false;
    for(char ch:inputString.toCharArray()){
        if(!alphabet.contains(ch)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only a schema of how to proceed and it's more like a general pattern,
in this case is adapted for your purpose.

 (accept only if first char is the same as last char)

This a DFA for your problem.

[image]

Basically there are states inside(circles) and transitions(arrows)


States:

S1->start state (always start from here)

S2,S3 -> intermediary (when input is finish and this state then not accepted)

S4,S5 -> final state (input finish and this state then accepted)`

Transitions[movements array]

(StateA, StateB, char) : going from SA to SB with char

(S1,S3,a) : T1

(S1,S2,b) : T2

(S3,S3,b) : T3

(S3,S4,a) : T4

(S4,S4,a) : T5

(S2,S2,a) : T6

(S4,S3,b) : T7

(S2,S5,b) : T8

(S5,S2,a) : T9

(S5,S5,b) : T10

Eg:
1:abb

(S1,a)->S3 by T1

(S3,b)->S3 by T3

(S3,b)->S3 by T3

End on S3 and input is not accepted

2:babb

(S1,b)->S2 by T2

(S2,a)->S2 by T6

(S2,b)->S5 by T9 (accepted if input is finish:bab, here not)

(S5,b)->S5 by T10

End on S5 and input is accepted

For any other char encounter that is not in alphabet just return immediately with not accepted.

For coding, need to add states and transitions.When checking the input char by char on
each step then update the current state properly.

Hope to be useful for you.